# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. not working

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am getting this error when filling form on my landing page:
Here is the code in thankyou.php

```
<?php
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'webmail.example.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'digital';
        $mail->Password = '*******';
        $mail->setFrom('digital@example.com', 'example');
        $mail->addReplyTo('sales@example.com', 'example');
        $mail->addAddress('sales@example.com', 'example');
        $name_field = $_POST['name'];
        $mobile_field = $_POST['mobile'];
        $project_field = $_POST['project'];
        $utm_source_field = $_POST['USOURCE'];
        $utm_medium_field = $_POST['UMEDIUM'];
        $utm_campaign_field = $_POST['UCAMPAIGN'];

        $mail->Subject = "Website Inquiry - $project_field";
        $mail->msgHTML($body);

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            ?>
            <script>alert('<?php echo $error ?>');</script><?php
        } 
        else {
            echo '';
            header("Location: thankyou.html");
        }
    }
?>
```

With the same setting if I upload files to another server it is working fine without any issue.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, did you replace example.com with your actual SMTP server in the code?

If not, that's your issue: use a real server.

Second, I notice that you used the subdomain:  webmail.*

Are you sure that domain points to a SMTP server, or is it just the web address for users to check their email?

Normally, SMTP servers are subdomained as:  smtp.example.com

You can check in your DNS records to see probe for an email server like this:

`dig exmaple.com mx`

The returning list of MX servers are good candidates to try.

Assuming you've got the server correct: Some ISPs in some countries notoriously block mail ports in order to curb spam. You can debug your network link by using telnet manually from terminal.

`telnet webmail.example.com 587`

If you get an interactive response, then you could figure it has something to do with the authentication. If you get no response, then you know the problem is in the networking transport.

Check to see if your ISP is allowing port 587, and also that your SMTP server has the firewall port open.

Comment: 1. yes, I replaced url with Example.com

Comment: 2. host  = webmail.example.com is correct & have used previously which was working also.

Is there anything wrong with PHP code?

Comment: Yes, the code looks fine to me.

Have you tried run telnet from terminal?:

`telnet webmail.example.com 587`

Does that connect?

Comment: Also, try this, many suggestions:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Hey I tried running telnet from terminal?: telnet webmail.example.com 587 But it does connect successfully. Now what else could be the issue? The same configuration works fine with other server but not on my server.